# A question on limits using the epsilon-delta definition

Tags: limits, functions, epsilon-delta

I am trying to solve this problem but I keep getting stuck. This question does not seem to be particularly hard.
The question is stated below:
$
|f(x)| < \frac{1}{100} 
$ if $0 < x < \delta$
Find $\delta$ if $f(x) = x\sin(x)$

Please do not tell me the answer directly but help me understand it and point me in the right direction. That way I will learn more.

Thank you for helping and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think of what happens as you increase $x$. Up until what value of $x$ can you safely say that $|x \sin(x)|$ will always be less than 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

You may notice that $|\sin x|\le1$ and so $|f(x)|=|x\sin x|=|x||\sin x|\le|x|$.

Since $x>0,x=|x|$ and we have $|x|<\delta$. Thus $|f(x)|<\delta$ whenever $0<x<\delta$.

Can we select an appropriate positive $\delta$ to make $|f(x)|<1/100$ true?

Comment: well the answer given is that delta is 0.1 so I do not know if we are allowed to select a delta to make the statement |f(x)| < 1/100 true. Thanks for the input.

Comment: The question is asking you to find a $\delta$ to make $|f(x)|<1/100$ true when $0<x<\delta$...the permissible value of $\delta$ is not unique!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$|\sin x|\le |x|$ for all $x$, so $|f(x)|\le\cdots$

Comment: so is |f(x)| < |x|? I am not so sure

Comment: No, better than $|x|$.

Comment: I know it seems like I am guessing. I am sorry.
So is |f(x)| < sin(x) then? if so how can we come to this conclusion?

Comment: No, you can conclude that $|f(x)|\le x^2$.

Comment: Oh I see thanks!!